# Error on getting JSON data from Couchbase DB in JAVA Restful API

Tags: java, json, api

Error on getting JSON data from Couchbase DB in JAVA Restful API.

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from  Couchbase DB and return it through an API.

Error :

> "HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
>   cannot be cast to com.couchbase.client.java.document.JsonDocument"

Code:

```
@Override
    public JsonDocument getProduct(String productId)
            throws URISyntaxException, IOException, InterruptedException, Exception {
        JsonDocument response = null;
        CouchbaseConnectionManager couchbaseConnectionManager = new CouchbaseConnectionManager();
        response = (JsonDocument) couchbaseConnectionManager.getCouchbaseClient().get(productId);
        return response;
    }
```

Could you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the API returns a string and you are casting to a JsonDocument. You could take the return as a string and then use org.json or other Json helpers to convert to JSON